# Multiple callback functions after a script file is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

The original HTML page just sequentially loads every js file. In the head, we load a cart.js file, and in the body, we have several script tags which are dependent on the cart.js.

Now we need to load the cart.js in $(window).load(). The code is like:

```
function loadJsAsync(sourceUrl, id) {
    var js, fjs = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (document.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = document.createElement('script'); js.type = 'text/javascript'; js.ansyc = true;
    js.id = id;
    js.src = sourceUrl;
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}
$(window).load(function () {
  loadJsAsync("<%=ScriptSourceUrl %>", 'cartjs');
});
```

After I added the code above, the cart.js is loaded after the entire page is load. However, those functions in the body script depending on it generates error.

In body scripts, I used

```
$('#cartjs').on('load', function(){})
```

to wrap those dependent functions but it did not work, because the #cartjs is dynamically added. Then I tried something like

```
$('body').load('#cartjs', function(){})
```

to wrap those dependent functions, it caused infinite loops which never stop. Besides, it just detect the load of the element of #cart, but not the load of the actual cart.js file.

I also saw someone mentioned $.getScript(), but I can't call it for every dependent function, since it would load the cart.js multiple times, and I hope to just load the cart.js once, and execute multiple functions dependent on it.

My current solution is to create an array called callbacks, and add those dependent functions to this array. Then add a

```
$('#cartjs').load(function(){})
```

in the loadJsAsync(), and in the callback of load() iterate the callbacks to execute all the dependent functions. It does not looks like a decent solution.

I am wondering if there are any solutions which can detect the load of the cart.js file, and then add those dependent functions as its callback, so that they can be executed after the cart.js is loaded.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think You should research on terms "dependency injection" which will probably lead you somehow to require.js

Comment: @Bartdude I was considering require.js before, but I don't think they'd like to add more external js file.

Comment: Well you'll need anyway some kind of mechanism to handle this kind of pattern, so either you re-invent the wheel probably without eventually making it a perfect circle, either you turn to existing solutions...

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use RequireJS, it perfectly fits your need, I believe, look at [here] (http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html) for the simple introduction.

The simple code snippet would be like this:

```
requirejs(["helper/util"], function(util) {
    //This function is called when scripts/helper/util.js is loaded.
    //If util.js calls define(), then this function is not fired until
    //util's dependencies have loaded, and the util argument will hold
    //the module value for "helper/util".
});
```

all functions in the wrap would be fired after the needed js loaded.